# C# pdfCreator COM Error - No valid ghostscript found

Tags: c#, com, pdf-generation

I'm trying to generate a pdf file using pdfforge PDFCreator.  The files look like they are being sent to the queue properly (the count of files looks right).  However when I get to the last line of code I am getting an error message.

pdfQueue.NextJob is throwing and error - No valid ghostscript version found.

I have no problems creating pdf's with pdfcreator directly from windows.

```
   pdfforge.PDFCreator.COM.Queue pdfQueue = new Queue();
   pdfQueue.Initialize();
   ProcessDirectory(targetDirectory);
   pdfQueue.WaitForJobs(4, 20);
   pdfQueue.MergeAllJobs();

   pdfforge.PDFCreator.COM.PrintJob job = pdfQueue.NextJob;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem and when I attempt to repeat it in separate computers, the problem no longer exists. So it is something very specific with the machine. The developers have recommended to go back to version 2.11 from the latest version 2.12 if you are using that but even that didn't seem to solve my problem. Waiting for answers from other expert members here.

Edit: I have the found the answer for my problem. I am writing this in vb.net and compiling with visual studio. Because of the way I was refrencing pdfCreator, pdfcreator dll files were being copied over to the bin directory but there was no ghostscript there. Because my application is simple, I just copied my exe on the desktop and it ran fine from there (I am assuming it then uses the com objects from the default registry address instead of within my bin directory). Installing ghost script to where your executable and its refrences are present might be another solution.

Someone more knowledgeable can correct with more accurate theory as to why this is the solution.

Comment: I pasted the "Ghostscript" folder from the PDFCreator installation folder to bin/Debug of my project and then it worked.